# Highcharts: reading data from a dictionary stored in a text file

Tags: javascript, python, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out how to get sensor data from a python script output into Highcharts.  Rather than write all my code directly in javascript, I decided to save the python sensor data as a dictionary in a text file.  My data.txt file looks like this:

```
    {'outdoor_temp': 45.7, 'outdoor_humid': 91.8}
```

The relevant portion of my Highcharts code looks like this:

```
    load: function () {
    var series = this.series[0];
    setInterval(function () {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), 
      file=fopen(data.txt,0)
      y = (file["outdoor_temp"]);
      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    }, 2000);
```

Why doesn't this read the dictionary value stored in data.txt?

Comment: If you want to store your data in files I would recommend you use JSON. Then you can just use `json.dumps()` in Python to write the dictionary to the file and within the JavaScript program use `fs.readFile()` to read the file and `JSON.parse(filecontent)` to get the data as a JS object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store your data in files I would recommend you use [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). JSON is supported out of the box by both Python and JavaScript and is very easy to work with.

#### Write file using Python

```py
import json

data = {'outdoor_temp': 45.7, 'outdoor_humid': 91.8}

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

The created `data.json` file then looks like this:

```json
{"outdoor_temp": 45.7, "outdoor_humid": 91.8}
```

#### Read file using Node and JavaScript

You can then read the created file using the following Node program:

```js
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

// await can only be used in an async function 
(async () => {
  const file = await readFile("data.json", { encoding: "utf-8"});
  const parsed = JSON.parse(file);
  // log all data
  console.log(parsed);
  // log outdoor temperature
  console.log(parsed.outdoor_temp)
})()
```

> Please note: You will need to implement some error handling for the above programs yourself.

#### Remarks

If you want to store the data and maybe do some calculations, do more visualizations etc. I recommend you use a database such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) or a [timeseries database](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-database/) such as [InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/products/influxdb-overview/) instead of single files. [Grafana](https://grafana.com/oss/grafana/) has integrations for them as well if you are looking for some nice visualization tool for your data.

Comment: Thanks, and I appreciate the additional recommendations.  It is probably time for me to move to my first DB rather than writing text files.